# Endless Scrolling with Code in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, background, scroll

I am programming a side-scrolling game.
I want to be able to control the speed of the endless side-scrolling background relative to the speed and position the player is moving at.

I want to know how to do a few things:

- Like, if the player is running, the background scrolls faster. If the
- Player is walking, the background scrolls slower. If the player isn't
- Moving, the background shouldn't be moving. If the it is at the start
- Or end of the level, the background should stop moving too.

Anyone can give me insight on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple formula that can do this for you:

Adjust the position of the background elements to be a percentage of the foreground elements. The lower the percentage, the slower they will move with the rest of the game.

Sample:

```
background.x = player.x * 0.2;
background.y = player.y * 0.2;
```

The `background` will always move at 20% of the speed of the `player`. When the `player` moves  200 pixels, the `background` will only scroll 40 pixels.

Comment: what if i want an endless scrolling background? whose scrolling speed is relative to the player?

Answer (score 0):

These are my favorites frameworks to develop scrolling games:

http://flixel.org/

http://flashpunk.net/

Comment: sry, but i can't use them for my project. i have to use fd and flash

Comment: @DevITper Those are both frameworks that you use *with* Flash.. They're just AS3 libraries.